# How To Fix 404 errors caused by Google Indexing Wordpress In Subdirectory

Tags: redirect, htaccess, google

I moved WordPress out of the root of my server into a special folder of its own and now Google is indexing my posts together with that special WordPress folder thus creating some 404 error issues.

For example let's say my WordPress core files are installed in `https://www.example.com/wordpress/` but the home page is `https://www.example.com/`.

This post link `https://www.example.com/hello-world/435/` works fine and has been indexed by Google. Unfortunately, Google is also indexing `https://www.example.com/wordpresshttps://www.example.com/hello-world/435/` thus creating 404 errors in Google Search console.

So my question is, is there a way to use `.htaccess` to make links like `https://www.example.com/wordpresshttps://www.example.com/hello-world/435/` to redirect to the right link which is `https://www.example.com/hello-world/435/`?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it using the rule below

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)wordpresshttps:/www.example.com/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: If you are seeing URLs like `https://www.example.com/wordpresshttps://www.example.com/hello-world/435/` indexed in the SERPs then it suggests you have an error with your internal links (this isn't the result of simply moving WP to a subdirectory). Unless you have fixed this underlying error with your links then simply implementing a redirect in `.htaccess` (which you will need to do anyway for SEO) will not be a satisfactory "fix". Google wouldn't be "indexing" these URLs unless it found them somehow. (Although why it would index 404s is another matter - have these always been 404s?)

Comment: @MrWhite when I made the move, I scanned thoroughly for such errors and found none. At the moment I can't find where (on my site) Google is getting those bad links from. Like you said, it's strange google will be indexing 404 errors. Ever since I detected those URLs, they've always thrown up 404 errors